# Proof that pseudorandom generators implies one-way function

Tags: complexity-theory, pseudo-random-generators, one-way-functions

I'm reading [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator_theorem#PRG_%E2%86%92_OWF) on Wikipedia that the existence of pseudorandom generators implies the existence of one-way functions.

My understanding is that *pseudorandom generators* are defined as

> A function $G_l:\{0,1\}^l\to\{0,1\}^m$ is a pseudorandom generator if all of the following hold:
>
> a. $l<m$
>
> b. $G_l\in\mathbf P$
>
> c. For any polynomially-sized circuit $C$,
> $$ \left|\Pr_{x\sim\text{Unif}\{0,1\}^l}[C(x)=1]-\Pr_{x\sim\text{Unif}(D)}[C(x)=1]\right|<\text{poly}(n),
>  $$
> where $D$ is the image of $G_l$.

and that *one-way functions* are defined as:

> A function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ is a one-way function if all of the following hold:
>
> 1. $f$ is invertible
> 2. $f\in\mathbf P$
> 3. For any polynomially-sized circuit $C$,
>
> $$
>  \Pr[f(C(f(x))=f(x)]<\text{poly}(n).
>  $$

**Question 1:** Looking at definitions for *one-way functions* above, I assume that the notation $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ refers to a *family* of functions $\mathcal F=\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbf N}$, where each $f_n$ is an invertible function $\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$. (And analogously for the defintion of pseudorandom generators.) **Is this assumption correct?**

The proof that pseudorandom generators implies one-way functions given on the Wikipedia page starts off with:

> Consider a pseudorandom generator $G_l:\{0,1\}^l\to\{0,1\}^{2l}$. Let's create the following one-way function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ that uses the first half of the output of $G_l$ as its output. Formally,
> $$
> f(x,y)\to G_l(x)
> $$

**Question 2:** What exactly is this saying? It looks like $|x|+|y|=n$, so I'll assume for now that $|x|=l=n/2$, in which case $G_l(x)$ outputs a string of length $2l=n$.  But if $G$ ignores $y$, how can $f$ be injective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-way functions need not be invertible. A one-way function which is invertible is known as a *one-way permutation*.

Here is the definition of one-way function from Goldreich's [primer](http://index-of.es/z0ro-Repository-2/Cryptography/Foundations%20of%20Cryptography%20A%20Primer%20-%20Oded%20Goldreich.pdf):

> A function $f\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ is *one-way* if it can be computed in polynomial time, and is hard to invert: for every polynomial time algorithm $A$, $$ \Pr_{x \in \{0,1\}^n}[f(A(f(x),1^n))) = x] \text{ is negligible}. $$

(A function $\epsilon(n)$ is negligible if $\epsilon(n) = O(1/n^k)$ for all $k$.)

As you can see, there is no promise that $|f(x)| = |x|$; it could be that $f(x)$ is longer than $x$, or even shorter than $x$ (which is why we feed $A$ the auxiliary input $1^n$, an arbitrary string of length $n$).